# How to install additional definitions of a typescript module?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I am trying to install the module [log4ts](https://github.com/koroandr/log4ts), which has some optional type definitions for its Layouts and Appenders. These implementations are not included in the main [log4ts.d.ts](https://github.com/koroandr/log4ts/blob/master/build/log4ts.d.ts) definition file. However, they are included separately, for example, [here is the ConsoleAppender definition](https://github.com/koroandr/log4ts/blob/master/build/appenders/ConsoleAppender.d.ts). My question, is how do I install these additional definition files?

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
npm install log4ts --save
typings install npm:log4ts/build/log4ts.d.ts --save --global
```

This allows me to import the types that are in this main definition:

```
// Works!
import { Logger, LoggerConfig } from "log4ts";
```

Now attempting to install an additional type definition:

```
typings install npm:log4ts/build/appenders/ConsoleAppender.d.ts --save
```

Attempting to import:

```
import { ConsoleAppender } from "log4ts";
import { ConsoleAppender } from "log4ts/ConsoleAppender";
```

Both of these give the error message: "Module log4ts has no exported member 'ConsoleAppender'"

My `typings.json`, after the above install commands, looks like:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "log4ts": "npm:log4ts/build/log4ts.d.ts",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160720070758",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654",
    "source-map": "registry:dt/source-map#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "uglify-js": "registry:dt/uglify-js#2.6.1+20160316155526",
    "webpack": "registry:dt/webpack#1.12.9+20160724112410"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "log4ts": "npm:log4ts/build/appenders/ConsoleAppender.d.ts"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`log4ts/ConsoleAppender.d.ts`](https://github.com/koroandr/log4ts/blob/master/build/appenders/ConsoleAppender.d.ts) you have a default export

```
export default class ConsoleAppender extends BaseAppender implements IAppender {
    append(entry: LogEntry): void;
    clear(): void;
}
```

So in order for your code to work you just need to import the default export.

```
import ConsoleAppender from "log4ts/ConsoleAppender"; // Without the { }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized the difference between the import types. For reference for others, the types are explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing it with --global parameter too?

Comment: Yes, but that results in an error: "Attempted to compile "log4ts" as a global module, but it looks like an external module. You'll need to remove the global option to continue."